# Code is Not able to find my function in Python(Spark) class

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need some help regarding the error in code. My Code consists of retrieving the zomato reviews and storing it in HDFS and again reading it performing Recommender Analtyics on it. I am getting a problem regarding my function is not recognizing in pyspark code. I am not entirely pasting the code as it might be confusing so i am writing a small similar use case for your easy understanding.

I am trying to read a file from local and converting it to dataframe from rdd and performing some operations and  again converting it to rdd and performing map operation to have delimiter by '|' and then save it to HDFS.
When i try to call self.filter_data(y) in lambda func of check function its not recognizing and giving me error as

> Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference
>   SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation.
>   SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run
>   on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

****CAN ANY ONE HELP ME WHY MY FILTER_DATA FUNCTION IS NOT RECOGNISING? SHOULD I NEED TO ADD ANY THING OR ANY THING WRONG IN THE WAY I AM CALLING. PLEASE HELP ME. THANKS IN ADVANCE****

**INPUT VALUE**

starting
 0|0|ffae4f|0|https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/user_profile_pictures/565/aed32fa2eb18bb4a5a3ba426870fd565.jpg?fit=around%7C100%3A100&crop=100%3A100%3B%2A%2C%2A|https://www.zomato.com/akellaram87?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1|2.5|FFBA00|Well...|unknown|16946626|2017-08-01T00-25-43.455182Z|30059877|Have been here for a quick bite for lunch, ambience and everything looked good, food was okay but presentation was not very appealing. We or...|2017-04-15 16:38:38|Big Foodie|6|Venkata Ram Akella|akellaram87|Bad Food|0.969352505662|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|0|0|1|0|0|0.782388212399

ending

starting

1|0|ffae4f|0|https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/user_profile_pictures/4d1/d70d7a57e1bfdf296ff4db3d8daf94d1.jpg?fit=around%7C100%3A100&crop=100%3A100%3B%2A%2C%2A|https://www.zomato.com/users/sm4-2011696?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1|1|CB202D|Avoid!|unknown|16946626|2017-08-01T00-25-43.455182Z|29123338|Giving a 1.0 rating because one cannot proceed with writing a  review, without rating it. This restaurant deserves a 0 star rating. The qual...|2017-01-04 10:54:53|Big Foodie|4|Sm4|unknown|Bad Service|0.964402034541|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|0.814540622345

ending

My code:

```
if __name__== '__main__':
     import os,logging,sys,time,pandas,json;from subprocess
     import PIPE,Popen,call;from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
     from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
     conf = SparkConf().setAppName('test')
     sc = SparkContext(conf = conf,pyFiles=['/bdaas/exe/nlu_project/spark_classifier.py','/bdaas/exe/spark_zomato/other_files/spark_zipcode.py','/bdaas/exe/spark_zomato/other_files/spark_zomato.py','/bdaas/exe/spark_zomato/conf_files/spark_conf.py','/bdaas/exe/spark_zomato/conf_files/date_comparision.py'])
     from pyspark.sql import Row, SQLContext,HiveContext
     from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
     sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
     import sys,logging,pandas as pd
     import spark_conf
     n = new()
     n.check()



class new:
   def __init__(self):
     print 'entered into init'


   def check(self):
    data = sc.textFile('file:///bdaas/src/spark_dependencies/classifier_data/final_Output.txt').map(lambda x: x.split('|')).map(lambda z: Row(restaurant_id=z[0], rating = z[1], review_id = z[2],review_text = z[3],rating_color = z[4],rating_time_friendly=z[5],rating_text=z[6],time_stamp=z[7],likes=z[8],comment_count =z[9],user_name = z[10],user_zomatohandle=z[11],user_foodie_level = z[12],user_level_num=z[13],foodie_color=z[14],profile_url=z[15],profile_image=z[16],retrieved_time=z[17]))
    data_r = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)
    data_r.show()
    d = data_r.rdd.collect()
    print d
    data_r.rdd.map(lambda x: list(x)).map(lambda y: self.filter_data(y)).collect()

    print data_r



  def filter_data(self,y):
    s = str()
    for i in y:
        print i.encode('utf-8')
        if i != '':
            s = s + i.encode('utf-8') + '|'
    print s[0:-1]
    return s[0:-1]
```

Comment: Thanx for "not entirely pasting the code as it might be confusing", but what the heck is the mess after INPUT VALUE? Plus, writing in bold + capital will not help attract attention...

Comment: @desertnaut Can you just see it now and debug my error?